# svn-multi and spaces in file names

Tags: pdftex, revision-control, svn-multi

I am a happy user of svn-multi latex package. My quality department now requires new file names including spaces.

When I changed the file name including a space, I get the following latex error:

```
Package: svn-multi 2011/08/30 v2.4d SVN Keywords for multi-file LaTeX documents

)
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@svn@scandate@ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.194 
      
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

The latex source code line is:

```
\usepackage{svn-multi}
\svnid{$Id: H4FB105 Benutzerhandbuch.tex 8085 2022-08-25 15:02:54Z oehhar $}
```

If the space in the file name is replaced by an underscore:

```
\usepackage{svn-multi}
\svnid{$Id: H4FB105_Benutzerhandbuch.tex 8085 2022-08-25 15:02:54Z oehhar $}
```

the process passes normally.

Is it advisable to post a bug report in:

https://sourceforge.net/p/svn-multi/tickets/

---

To avoid the issue, I used:

```
\svnidlong
{$HeadURL: svn://elmifile/manual/H4FB105%20Benutzerhandbuch.tex $}
{$LastChangedDate: 2022-08-25 17:45:44 +0200 (Do, 25. Aug 2022) $}
{$LastChangedRevision: 8087 $}
{$LastChangedBy: oehhar $}
```

This worked well.

Nevertheless, it would be great, if Id would also work. I prefer it, as it is more compact and I don't need the URL feature.

Am I overseeing something obvious or is this a bug ?
Any help appreciated.

---

Environment:

- Windows 10 64 bit OS
- MikTex
- svn-multi 2011/08/30 v2.4d
- pdftex
- TexStudio

---

Thank you all,
Harald

Comment: I am surprised that the filename is not encoded, i.e. the space is not written as %20 as in the URL keyword.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of `svn-multi` and assumed that the filename would be encoded so that spaces are written as `%20` as it is the case with the URL keyword.

To support this the ID scanner must be adjusted. I will add this to the package and release it soon.

---

Solution: I now add (back) a space after the username (as it gets removed beforehand) and check for an empty field after the last space. If it is not empty there are more fields as expected so the first two are part of the file name. Then I repeat this scanning until the last field is empty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svn-multi}
\makeatletter

\def\svnkwsave@readargs#1{%
    \svnkwsave@read#1\relax
  \endgroup
  \if@svnidsw
    \ifx\svnkwId\empty\else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \svn@scanId\expandafter\svnkwId\space\relax
      \@svnidswfalse
    \fi
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
}

\def\svn@scanId@#1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6\relax{%
  \@svn@scandate{#3 #4}%
  \svnkwdef{Filename}{#1}%
  \svnkwdef{Date}{#3 #4}%
  \svnkwdef{Revision}{#2}%
  \svnkwdef{Author}{#5}%
  \@svn@updateid{\svnkw{Revision}}{\svnkw{Date}}{\svnkw{Author}}{\svnkw{URL}}%
}

\def\svn@scanId@#1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6\relax{%
  \begingroup
  \def\@tempa{#6}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty
    \endgroup
    \@svn@scandate{#3 #4}%
    \svnkwdef{Filename}{#1}%
    \svnkwdef{Date}{#3 #4}%
    \svnkwdef{Revision}{#2}%
    \svnkwdef{Author}{#5}%
    \@svn@updateid{\svnkw{Revision}}{\svnkw{Date}}{\svnkw{Author}}{\svnkw{URL}}%
  \else
    \def\@tempa{\svn@scanId@{#1 #2} #3 #4 #5 #6\relax}%
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\@tempa
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\svnid{$Id: H4FB105 Benutzerhandbuch.tex 8085 2022-08-25 15:02:54Z oehhar $}
\begin{document}
\svnkw{Revision}

\svnkw{Date}

\svnkw{Author}

\svnkw{URL}

\svnkw{Filename}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

if your filenames always have a `.` you can prevent a split on spaces before the `.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svn-multi}
\makeatletter
\def\svn@scanId@#1.#2 #3 #4 #5 #6\relax{%
  \@svn@scandate{#4 #5}%
  \svnkwdef{Filename}{#1.#2}%
  \svnkwdef{Date}{#4 #5}%
  \svnkwdef{Revision}{#3}%
  \svnkwdef{Author}{#6}%
  \@svn@updateid{\svnkw{Revision}}{\svnkw{Date}}{\svnkw{Author}}{\svnkw{URL}}%
}
\makeatother
\svnid{$Id: H4FB105 Benutzerhandbuch.tex 8085 2022-08-25 15:02:54Z oehhar $}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix, that looks great. Nevertheless, it feals like a work around and not like a fix to the issue.

Comment: @HaraldOehlmann sure  yes a full fix would count spaces back from `$` so picking out size date time username `$` and everything before that would be filename, but by the time you have done that you are not really using `svn-multi` at all, this is a rather more focussed extension of the existing code

Comment: Good idea for nomal filenames, but the filename could also have multiple dots in it and contain a space after the first dot. Then this would fail as well.